# How can I properly send a Synced External Application Image to a RESTful WCF

Tags: android

I'm newbie to Android, I'm trying to send some Images from Android to a RESTFul WCF.

By now I'm being able to select the Images from the Gallery and sending them to the Server.

the WCF is expecting the image as `Stream`

But I'm having problems with the Synced Images that get stored in the Tablet Like the  Facebook or G+ photos. (I don't know if they are cached or something)

I'm using this function to get the path of the Image

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
         String path = null;
         if (contentUri.getScheme().toString().compareTo("content")==0)
         {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };           
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);
         }
         else

         {
             path = contentUri.getPath();
         }
         Log.i(TAG, path);
         return path;
        }
```

With that kind of images I get an internet path like:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s2048x2048/432098_10151223392360790_398885469_n.jpg

Just for clarity and to remark. I get a "content" scheme.. so I get the path from the "if " something like:

```
content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5703464571893262194
```

To send it to the Server im using MultipartEntity, because I saw in others post here in SO to do so, like this:

```
 ((MultipartEntity) oInputEntity).addPart(
                            "fileContents",
                            new FileBody(new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(context,
                                            imageUri)),

 "image/jpeg"));
```

With that kind of images I was getting a `FileNotFoundEception` I think it's because the image path is an Internet path, so the MultiPartEntity don't know how to retrieve it,

So I changed my method to download the image and now is working with this code

```
public static File getFileFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
             String path = IntUtilities.getRealPathFromURI(context, contentUri);
             Log.i(TAG, path);
             final File file;
             if (path.startsWith("http") || path.startsWith("/http") )
             {
                 //if its an image form internet lets download it and save it in our directory and return that file
                // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
                final String fname = "BIR" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";
                final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "BIR");
                root.mkdirs();
                file = new File(root, fname);    


                try {
                     final URL url = new URL(path);
                     final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                             .openConnection();
                     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                     urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                     urlConnection.connect();
                     final FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                     final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    int downloadedSize = 0;

                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                     int bufferLength = 0;
                     while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                         fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                         downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                     }
                     // close the output stream when done
                     fileOutput.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
             else
             {          
                 file = new File(path);
             }
             return file;
            }
```

---

```
  ((MultipartEntity) oInputEntity).addPart(
                                "fileContents",
                                new FileBody(Utilities.getFileFromURI(context,
                                                imageUri),

     "image/jpeg"));
```

But I'm not comfortable with this solution, seems like double effort, I turned off my Wifi and 3g in the tablet, also turned off and on the tablet iself and I still see those images, so I'm guessing they got copied locally or cached on the tablet when they were synced for the first time. I looked for them when attached to my computer (in Windows Explorer) to see if they were there, but I dont see them, maybe I'm doing something wrong or dont know the storage folder.

The main reason that I dont like this solution is that if you don't have Internet on the moment, obviously the image will not be downloaded, and the app I'm making is supposed to work offline, and well.. the Image is there, there shouldn't be a request to internet to guess a local image.

Being said this, is there a way to find the real/physical path of this Photos that were synced, that have an http or https scheme to send this images using the MultiPartEntity?

Or another proper way to send this Images to the Server?

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

from the chooser dialog , you can always get a bitmap

chooser-->$Result->getData() = imageUri

from the imageUri, get a Bitmap by running the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Once you get the bitmap..,

you can put it to a fileSink

you can use a Hashmap to cache it in Memory

```
mBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
    mCR.openInputStream(imageUri),  null,  options);

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
mBitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, minVal, os);
mload.memoryCache.putbig(file.toURI().toURL().toString(), mBitMap);
```

and you can http POST the Bitmap directly by loading its ByteArray to the Entity...

```
case POST:

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);                  
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                 
float tmp = (float) 1024 * 1024 / bmp.getByteCount();
int minVal = (Math.round(tmp * 100) < 101) ? Math.round(tmp * 100): 100;
if (bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, minVal, stream)){      
    httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(stream.toByteArray()));
}else{ //TODO need to format actual message
    handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler,
    HttpConnection.DID_ERROR, new Exception("ERR bitmap NG")));
                    }
```

background on the POST method is [here](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/)

[lazyloader project](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) is a good template to use.

So why use mimeMultipartEntity with a file when you can operate directly on the bytes in the bitMap? As soon as you have a Uri, get a Bitmap and use the bitmap/ Uri pair for the basis of your interface to memCache, interface to HTTP POST, interface to fileSink used to retrieve local file when you have CacheMiss. This will help minimize doing everything on the basis of a file.

Think about using a Map [hashON(Uri.toString() :: bitMap] to store the images that you process locally. Then when you want to POST an image , you can just retrieve it from the map and POST its bytes directly in a "ByteArrayEntity".